# Getting [BC30205] end of statement expected error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I'm new to SSRS and trying to apply an "if then else logic" to display data onto a table from different datasets based on a parameter entry value. Following is my expression code :

```
=iif(Parameters!ReportType.Value = "AE", Fields!company_name.Value,
"HRMS_DS_AllEmployees"), iif(Parameters!ReportType.Value = "JE",
Fields!company_name.Value, "HRMS_DS_JoiningEmployees"),
iif(Parameters!ReportType.Value = "LE", Fields!company_name.Value,
"HRMS_DS_LeavingEmployees","")
```

HRMS_DS_AllEmployees/HRMS_DS_JoiningEmployees/HRMS_DS_LeavingEmployees are my different datsets

I know this may be some elementary mistake that I'm making but would be grateful if someone could point out my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is wrong unfortunately. I understand what you are trying to do but switching between datasets like this is not, as far as I know, possible as there is no context. Typically you would specify the dataset as your scope only if you wanted to use the entire dataset as part of your expression. So, for exmaple you could swap `Fields!company_name.Value,
"HRMS_DS_AllEmployees"` with `FIRST(Fields!company_name.Value,"HRMS_DS_AllEmployees")` but this would always return the first company_name from the entire dataset.

I think you need to change your approach.

Can you not combine your dataset queries to give you a single dataset that contains all employees with joiners and leavers indicated by a status column or some kind? Then your report could just filter that column based on the parameter.

Better still, change your report dataset query to only return the data you need based on the parameter.

So your dataset query might look something like (just made up the criteria but you get the idea)

```
SELECT * FROM myEmployeesTable e 
    WHERE 
        (@ReportType = 'AE')
        OR
        (@ReportType = 'JE' AND DATEDIFF(d , e.JoinDate, getdate()) < 30)
        OR
        (@ReportType = 'LE' AND DATEDIFF(d , e.LeaveDate, getdate()) < 30)
```

Comment: Ahh I see. I have accomplished what I need using a single dataset and was just exploring other ways to accomplish the same. Thanks for your suggestion my solution works along similar lines.